# Returning Value from Function to Variable

Tags: python, function, variables

So I'm currently having some trouble with working out how to basically create a "count" function work within my Rock, Paper, Scissors game. I'm new to Python and this is my first foray into the use of multiple functions to execute game logic. Here's my code...

```
import random
from random import choice

cpu_score = 0
player_score = 0

# dictionary from which gestures are pulled
gestures = ["rock","paper","scissors"]

n_rounds = int(input("How many rounds would you like to play? "))

while n_rounds % 2 == 0 or n_rounds <= -1:
    print("Number of rounds must be an odd number! Select an odd number!")
    n_rounds = input("How many rounds?")
    break
print("Lets play",n_rounds,"rounds!")

rounds_to_win = ((n_rounds + 1)//2)
rounds_to_win = round(rounds_to_win)
print("You must win",rounds_to_win,"rounds to beat the game!")

def computer_choice():
    """Movement made by the computer"""
    comp = random.choice(gestures)   
    return comp

def player_gesture():
    """Movement by player"""
    player = input("Please select, rock, paper or scissors")
    if player not in gestures:
        print("That's not an option! Please try again.")
        player = input("Please select, rock, paper or scissors")  
    return player

def who_won_round(comp, player):
    '''Who is the winner of the round.'''

    winner = 0     

    if ((player == "rock") and (comp == "paper")) or \
            ((player == "paper") and (comp ==  "scissors")) or \
            ((player == "scissors") and (comp == "rock")):
          winner = 1

    elif ((comp == "rock") and (player == "paper")) or \
            ((comp == "paper") and (player == "scissors")) or \
            ((comp == "scissors") and (player == "rock")):
          winner = 2

    else:
        winner = 0

    return winner

def win_counter(winner, cpu_score,player_score):

    rounds = 1

    if winner == 1:
        player_score += 1
        print("This is round",rounds)
        rounds += 1
        return player_score

    if winner == 2:
        cpu_score += 1
        print("This is round",rounds)
        rounds += 1
        return cpu_score

def count_round(winner, player, comp, cpu_score, player_score):

    if winner == 0:
        print("It's a tie!")      

    elif winner == 1:

        print("The player chose",player)
        print("The computer chose",comp)
        print("The computer won the round!")
        print("The computer has won",cpu_score,"rounds!")

    elif winner == 2:
        print("The player chose",player)
        print("The computer chose",comp)
        print("The player won the round!")
        print("The player has won",player_score,"rounds!")

def game_structure():
    while rounds_to_win < n_rounds:
        comp = computer_choice()
        player = player_gesture()
        winner = who_won_round(comp,player)
        win_count = win_counter(winner, cpu_score,player_score)
        count = count_round(winner, player, comp, cpu_score, player_score)

game_structure()
```

Basically I'm having issues returning the variables in order to keep count of the scores of the "number of rounds" and "cpu_score" and "player_score". I prefer to not declare global variables as I realise they can be messy to use, but I'm not quite sure how to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

If you must avoid the use of global variables, you should take an object oriented approach. That way you can store the variables in the object.

So basically you do something like this:

```
newgame = mytictactoe()

while True #infinite loop
    input("wanna play?")
    if input == yes:
        newgame.start
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

From what I see, the `cpu_score` and `player_score` are never updated. You only have the newest result in `win_count`, that is not assigned to `cpu_score` or `player_score` at anytime. It could be something like:

```
win_count = win_counter(winner, cpu_score,player_score)
if winner == 1:
    cpu_score = win_count
if winner == 2:
    player_score = win_count
rounds_to_win = max(player_score, cpu_score)
count_round(winner, player, comp, cpu_score, player_score)
```

I did not run it, but this modifications should do the trick. There are better ways of doing it; maybe using a list to keep the scores and use winner as the index, or an object approach as someone else said, but I do not want to change too much the code.

Also, bear in mind that the `round` variable in `win_counter` does nothing.